# issue to bind a a List<> to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I bound a list to a datagridview (using a Bindingsource).
But my DataGridView never fills.
Is there any reason why?

Here is the code:

```
  {
        public BindingList<Rat> list = new BindingList<Rat>();
        BindingSource bs;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = list;

            list.Add(new Rat(12, "Hubert", "cousin"));
            list.Add(new Rat(7, "Joe", "taxi driver"));
            list.Add(new Rat(3, "Bill", "DaBoss"));

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }

    }

    public class Rat
    {
        public int Age;
        public string Name;
        private string Nickname;

        public Rat(int age, string name, string nick)
        {
            Age = age;
            Name = name;
            Nickname = nick;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try change fields into properties in `Rat` class

```
public int Age { get; set }
public string Name { get; set }
private string Nickname { get; set }
```